# How to handle animations using flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, bloc

I have read almost every tutorial at https://bloclibrary.dev/ but I have not found any mentions how to handle animations using Bloc. Is the solution use setState for local state management or there is any solution I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Animation is related to UI, It is recommended not to use state management for UI section.